# How do I pass a variable form my model to my controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am using the Zend Framework 2.  Below is my model code (FriendCallTable):

```
 $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
     return $id= $this->tableGateway->lastInsertValue;
```

Below is my controller code:

```
             $id = $this->FriendCallTable->id; 
             echo $id;
```

If I echo instead of return in the model I am getting the correct value.  I cannot figure out how to pass it though.  Thank you for your help and guidance.

Comment: Don't know if it helps you but you are accessing a property now while zf2 documentation says it's a method: getLastInsertValue()

Read here: http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/classes/Zend.Db.TableGateway.TableGateway.html

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do the below in the controller:

```
$id = $this->getFriendCallTable()->saveFriendCall($friendCall);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```
return $this->tableGateway->lastInsertValue;
```